# Yii2 - Update database field when switchinput widget is clicked

Tags: yii2

I am using the switchinput Kartik widget which I have related to a database true/false field (field1). What I want to do is to be able to update this database field value when I change the switch.

Here is the view code:

```
<?php 
    echo $form->field($model, 'field1')->widget(SwitchInput::classname(), [
    'type' => SwitchInput::CHECKBOX,
    'name' => 'status_11',
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'size' => 'medium',
        'onColor' => 'success',
        'offColor' => 'danger',
        'handleWidth'=>80,
        'onText'=>'ACTIVE',
        'offText'=>'INACTIVE'
    ]
        ]);
?>
```

and here is the controller code that tries to update the database:

```
.................    
if (isset($_POST['status_11']))
                    {
                        if ($model->field1 == False)
                        {
                            $model->field1 = True;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $model->field1 = False;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!$model->save())
                    {
                        throw new Exception('Could not save to database. Trnasaction aborted.');
                    }
..................
```

The switch can read from the database the value of field1 and show on or off respectively. But the change (onclick) action does not update the database...

Should I try using PHP or should I implement it with js ('pluginEvents' widget option) and how?
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `pluginEvents` array with the `switchChange` event, to trigger an ajax call to your php script, which updates the database:

```
pluginEvents = [
    "switchChange.bootstrapSwitch" => 'function() { 
        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "'.Url::to(['/controller/action']).'",
          data: { status_11: state}
      })
    }',
];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is it acceptable to put in url property a [controller/action] reference?

Comment: { status_11: state} gives me ReferenceError: state is not defined
but { status_11: this.checked } works