# yii2, partially render view with new data

Tags: php, yii2

New to yii2 and PHP, ran into a break here.
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128417/yii2-update-data-by-switch-toogle-using-ajax-pjax-in-gridview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064400/yii2-update-database-field-when-switchinput-widget-is-clicked) post, I tried recreating the AJAX call.
Right now, using the Kartik SwitchInput widget, I'm at least trying to get the value into the controller and then return it to another place on the index page.

Here's what's in the view

```
...
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $customers,
    'columns' => [
        ...
        [
            'label' => 'Status',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'value' => function($models){
                return SwitchInput::widget([
                    'name' => $models->id,
                    'value' => $models->status,
                    'pluginEvents' => [
                        'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => 'function(e) { 
                            $.ajax({
                                method: "POST",
                                url: "'.Url::to(['update-status']).'",
                                data: { "status": e.currentTarget.checked, "id": e.currentTarget.name },
                                error:function(res){
                                    console.log(res.responseText);
                                }
                            })
                            console.log(`${e.currentTarget.checked}  ${e.currentTarget.name}`);
                        }'
                    ]
...
```

Here's the controller:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller{
    public function actionIndex(){

        $customers = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Customer::find()
        ]);

        $models = $customers->getModels();

        return $this->render('index', [ 
            'customers' => $customers,
            'models' => $models
        ]);
    }

    public function actionUpdateStatus(){
        $status = Yii::$app->request->post('status');
        $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');

        return $this->renderPartial('index', [
            'status' => $status,
            'id' => $id
        ]);
    }
}
```

Whenever I flip the switch, it returns a 500 Internal error. Console.logging it revealed: $customers is undefined.
From what I realised, whenever I make an actionUpdateStatus call, Yii re-renders the view completely anyway, and tries to find the $customers, which isn't in the UpdateStatus.
How do I return the switch data, separately, back into the same view, then?

Comment: If you are using standard debug toolbar you can open the log for the request by clicking the ajax button in toolbar and then selecting link in profile column [like this](http://prntscr.com/sox33u). In log you should see some exception or error that caused error 500.

Comment: @MichalHynčica that's covered in point 4 at the bottom: I already looked through each and every tab in the debugger, there's no information or any type of response. I just tried a couple more tests, and if the results are correct, I'll have to rewrite the question completely... Thing is, a tad bit above is a variable called $customers - it's an ActiveDataProvider for the GridView, and the SwitchInput is a column inside it. I get $customers from the database in a separate action. Somehow after the ajax call it's affected and shows up as undefined - which might be the issue.

Comment: Why you're using the same view (`index`) in completely different contexts? `actionIndex()` and `actionUpdateStatus()` should have their own views.

Comment: @rob006 I slowly realise I'm doing something stupid. By my logic, actionIndex and actionUpdateStatus were separate: the former downloads the initial state/model/data and renders it in the view, the latter takes the status/id part and returns it in a separate place on the same view. Now I'm getting to the conclusion it doesn't work like this. How would I combine two views in a single window then - through layout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128417/yii2-update-data-by-switch-toogle-using-ajax-pjax-in-gridview) you mentioned, and i havent specified one thing there which is reloading of the gridview which wasnt the requirement there, but can be done using `$.pjax`.

A few things you need to look at

- You dont need any view for the `updateStatus` action as per your requirement.
- You just need to return some status code to the ajax call that you are using inside the gridView for the switch input, and refresh your gridview to load the new updated status.
- In ajax success callback function check if that status code is ok then you should refresh the gridview rather than using render partial.
- And you are not updating anything in the `updateStatus`? you need to switch the status

So change your action to the following

```
public function actionUpdateStatus()
{
    try {
        $status = Yii::$app->request->post('status');
        $id = Yii::$app->request->post('id');

        $model = Customer::findOne($id);
        $model->status=$status;
        if(!$model->save()){
           throw new Exception(implode("\n",\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->errors,'0'));
        }
        return $this->asJson(['success' => true]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->asJson(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
    }
}
```

Make sure you have wrapped the GridView inside Pjax start and end and add an `id` to the Pjax widget

```
<?php 
    Pjax::begin(['id'=>'pjax-container']);

    echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $customers,
    'columns' => [
    .......
    ]);

    Pjax::end();
 ?>
```

And your ajax call to the following

```
'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => 'function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "'.Url::to(['update-status']).'",
        dataType:'json',
        data: { "status": e.currentTarget.checked, "id": e.currentTarget.name },
        success:function(data){
             if(data.success){
                  $.pjax({container: "#pjax-container"});
             }else{
                  console.log(data.message);
             }
        },
        error:function(res){
            console.log(res.responseText);
        }
    });
}'
```

Comment: Gridview was taken from the other answer - I attempted to combine the two, and it didn't go all too well. Didn't look at pjax before aswell, thought the problem was definitely an incorrect route or data format. Trying to apply the code deleted that entry for good - but hey, at least it worked! I can figure the rest out. Thank you so much!